# Is there any lightweight Angular alternative?

Tags: dart

I come from Vue.js to Dart world, and Angular is look for me very heavy and ugly. Is there anything more lightweight and compact for client side?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/over_react, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdl, ...

Comment: Google `angular vs` and look at the dropdown for options, like react.

Comment: there's few '__') too bad.. 
https://github.com/yissachar/awesome-dart#client-web-app-frameworks

Comment: http://dodo.mikosoft.info - The Dodo as an alternative framework. Blazing fast, easy to learn, Javascript, frontend framework for reactive web pages & apps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something minimal, you might like [MDL](http://www.material-design-lite.pub/) and [over_react](https://workiva.github.io/over_react/). Even just using the SDK's [low-level DOM API](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tutorials/low-level-html) gets you a long way (compared to vanilla JS).

FWIW, AngularDart is getting less and less heavy each month, and on bigger projects it doesn't seem uglier than Vue.js to me -- but I understand everyone has their own preference.